# unable to schedule for few minutes

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I had scheduled an email for every 5 min but it is not working.

```
schedulers obj=new   schedulers ();
String sch = '0 5 ? ? ? 2022';
System.schedule('Job1', '1 10 * * * ?', obj);
System.schedule('Job2', '1 15 * * * ?', obj);
System.schedule('Job3', '1 20 * * * ?', obj);
```

I had scheduled class for every 5 min i get a mail but i am not getting

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, can you clarify further what is not working? As per the Salesforce docs, the schedules are not guaranteed to occur precisely on the time you define, if thats what your expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Salesforce [documentation](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_schedule_batch_apex.htm), the schedules are not guaranteed to occur precisely on the time you define, if thats what your expecting?

> Salesforce schedules the class for execution at the specified time. Actual execution may be delayed based on service availability.